# What does initImageAppleJPEG: falling back to libJPEG warning messages mean?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

After upgrading my iPhone 5s to iOS8, and using Xcode 6 GM and Xcode 6.0.1, I started to see this message on console:

`initImageAppleJPEG:1325: falling back to libJPEG`

Anyone else seeing this? I couldn't find an answer online. And I don't see crashes or anything. It might be just an impression, but I've noticed a few hiccups/slow downs when fast scrolling a list of images. Hard to say if it was there before, and I'm just noticing now because of these suspicious messages.

It might also be one of those warning messages that Apple forgets to hide each major Xcode release.

Comment: No one has any clue?

Comment: did you get any answer?

Comment: Not yet... I only have a suspicion. I'm using SDWebImage to asynchronously download images. Maybe it's some internal process they are using...

Comment: If you ask this on the Graphics section of [Apple's devforums](https://devforums.apple.com/) you may get an answer from someone on IMG at Apple about this.

Comment: @GuilhermeSprint no i do not think so..I am not using SDWebImage, still I am getting this

Comment: I got this and im not using SDWebImage either

Answer (score 6):

I've found this happens on perfectly valid JPEG images, so I presume that Apple didn't bother to implement all JPEG features in their own decoder, and has to use the de-facto standard libjpeg in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your images are jpg, I had this problem with png images.

Comment: i got this with png, flushed cache, deleted derived data and went away

Answer (score 1):

Check if the image URL has any spaces. You can remove the spaces from the url string and convert it into a URL using this extension in Swift.

```
    extension String{
    func spaceRemovedURL() -> URL{
        let url = self.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
        return URL(string: url)!
    }
}
```